# Deleting DataFrame rows in Pandas based on column values dynamically by taking values from a list

Tags: python, pandas

How do I transform the following code

```
list_of_things = [0,1,2,3,4...]

df = df[df.line_race != 0]
```

and make it dynamic by transforming the data frame if the value in line_race is in the list list_of_things I know I can easily achieve this using a loop but I would rather not if it can be helped.

```
            daysago  line_race rating        rw    wrating
 line_date                                                 
 2007-03-31       62         11     56  1.000000  56.000000
 2007-03-10       83         11     67  1.000000  67.000000
 2007-02-10      111          9     66  1.000000  66.000000
 2007-01-13      139         10     83  0.880678  73.096278
 2006-12-23      160         10     88  0.793033  69.786942
 2006-11-09      204          9     52  0.636655  33.106077
 2006-10-22      222          8     66  0.581946  38.408408
 2006-09-29      245          9     70  0.518825  36.317752
 2006-09-16      258         11     68  0.486226  33.063381
 2006-08-30      275          8     72  0.446667  32.160051
 2006-02-11      475          5     65  0.164591  10.698423
 2006-01-13      504          0     70  0.142409   9.968634
 2006-01-02      515          1     64  0.134800   8.627219
 2005-12-06      542          2     70  0.117803   8.246238
 2005-11-29      549          0     70  0.113758   7.963072
 2005-11-22      556          1     -1  0.109852  -0.109852
 2005-11-01      577          0     -1  0.098919  -0.098919
 2005-10-20      589          0     -1  0.093168  -0.093168
 2005-09-27      612          1     -1  0.083063  -0.083063
 2005-09-07      632          0     -1  0.075171  -0.075171
 2005-06-12      719          1     69  0.048690   3.359623
 2005-05-29      733          3     -1  0.045404  -0.045404
 2005-05-02      760          0     -1  0.039679  -0.039679
 2005-04-02      790          2     -1  0.034160  -0.034160
 2005-03-13      810          1     -1  0.030915  -0.030915
 2004-11-09      934          0     -1  0.016647  -0.016647
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
df = df[~df.line_race.isin(list_of_things)]
```